# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After i installed Android Studio 2.3 and updated my SDK then [the following  error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH7Pk.png) occurs. What can be done to solve this issue?

Comment: It's clear from your question title that your're using a Gradle version that werent released yet. The latest for latest build of AS is 2.3.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this in build.gradle.project

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
```

and this in build.gradle.module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.madridistansit.mapapplication"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
}
```

Comment: thank you brother for your great help. I am grateful to you

Answer (score -1):

if `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'` returns classpath error 
try this :`compile 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'`